# postgresql full text search query too slow

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, explain, sql-optimization

There are two sql in a table, one of them is too slow, any one can tell me what's wrong and how can i optimize it?

There is their query explain blow:
[image: slow query explain]

[---------edit---------]

[image: new query explain]

Comment: I have a gin index on field `title` and a b-tree index on field `city`;

Comment: For the future: please post execution plans as  [**formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) [not screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). You can also upload them to http://explain.depesz.com if you think they are too big to be posted here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bitmap index scan in the second query returns more rows because the condition is less selective.

As a consequence, the bitmap becomes too large to fit into `work_mem` and PostgreSQL continues by storing one bit per matching block rather than per matching row (those are the *lossy* entries mentioned).

So many more rows have to be checked during the bitmap heap scan, which causes the longer execution time.

Increase `work_mem` for better results.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Do you know any other option can optimize the sql? I set work_mem=64M,  it still need 300 ms...

Comment: I added a picture of new sql explain in question body, thanks~

Comment: This is just how long it takes - I don't think it can be optimized any further. It has to crunch a lot of data.

Comment: OK，I really appriciate it.